# How to stop AppOpenAd showing multiple times? (Unity)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I have implemented AppOpenAds from Admob, they work as intended...To a point.

Unfortunately, when the viewer is watching a 'rewarded' video (ie to get coins in-game) after it finishes, it then shows an AppOpenAd, as it obviously thinks the user has left the app (when they have just watched a video instead). So they are getting a double-whammy ad!

Is there any way I can stop this?

It's using this;

```
private void OnAppStateChanged(AppState state)
{
// Display the app open ad when the app is foregrounded.
UnityEngine.Debug.Log("App State is " + state);
if (state == AppState.Foreground)
{
AppOpenAdManager.Instance.ShowAdIfAvailable();
}
}
```

Edit - just to clarify - Rewarded ads work, they just then show an AppOpenAd when the rewarded ad finishes due to it thinking I was outside of the app.

Comment: https://docs.unity.com/ads/ImplementingRewardedAdsUnity.html This might be usefull for you!

Comment: Hi I think you may have misunderstood the question - the rewarded ad works, it just shows another ad after (AppOpen) as well.

Comment: Aah, So you automatticly run an ad on opening the game? And running a rewarded ad assumes it to leave/reopen the app?

Comment: Correct yes, it thinks viewing an ad is leaving the app

Comment: Have u tried putting the event to false on a timer? When the ad is watched u deactivate the event (AppOpen) for 5 seconds? Maybe a loophole but a propper chance of working.

Comment: How would this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a bool variable and while showing the rewarded ad make it true. Put a check of the variable in your code

```
if (!variable && state == AppState.Foreground)
{
AppOpenAdManager.Instance.ShowAdIfAvailable();
}
else
{
variable = false;
}
```